# Clojure: difference between how special forms, functions and macros are implemented

Tags: clojure

i have just started with Clojure. I am reading [this](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html#Intro).
I did not understand the difference between how special forms are implemented and how functions and macros are implemented where it says

*Nearly all functions and macros are implemented in Clojure source code. The differences between functions and macros are explained later. Special forms are recognized by the Clojure compiler and not implemented in Clojure source code.*

Can someone explain the difference between two things ? ( implemented in Clojure source code and not implemented in Clojure source code)

Comment: Special forms are analogous to keywords like "if" in other languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Implemented in Clojure source code**

The code for the particular feature/abstraction is implemented in clojure language itself i.e in .clj file.

**Not implemented in clojure source code**

It is implemented in Java code.

Check out the Clojure code on github and you will find that there is Java as well as clojure code.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps a more useful, from my perspective, way of putting it would be:

special forms are the parts of the language that, if someon took them away from you,
you would not be able to replace them, and would have to recover them
by other means.

for example if someone removed cond you could write your own cond macro (it's just a wrapper around if. should someone remove if ... you would have to fork the language and put it back.

Comment: I don't think this definition is either useful or accurate. For example, `let` can be implemented as a macro on top of `fn`, but that doesn't mean `let` isn't a special form (ignore here that `let` is actually a macro on top of the special form `let*`). And as posts like [Programming with Nothing](http://experthuman.com/programming-with-nothing) show, really the only special form you *need* is the function.

Comment: But is @Arthur Ulfeldt 's answer in the spirit of Clojure? Maybe he would straighten out the inaccurate parts.

Answer (score 1):

Plus a quote from book *Clojure Programming* by Chas Emerick, which I think was very helpful to understand Clojure's special forms. :]

> Special forms are Clojure's primitive building blocks of computation, on top of which all the rest of Clojure is built.
>
> Everything that isn't a special form is implemented in Clojure itself by bootstrapping from that limited set of primitive operations.
>
> Indeed, if you were so motivated, you could implement Clojure (or another language of your choosing) from scratch, on your own, on top of Clojure's special forms.

Answer (score 0):

`Special forms` are Clojure’s primitive building blocks of computation, on top of which
all the rest of Clojure is built.

`Functions` are first-class values in Clojure; creating them falls to the `fn` special form.